# Doctrine SVN missing folder structure

Tags: php, svn, orm, doctrine-orm

After checking Out the Doctrine SVN from GitHub:

http://svn.github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git

There are missing folders in lib/vendor/doctrine-common (Maybe others too)

My checked out version has nothing inside this folder (only the svn folder), yet the online folder structure shows the folders; lib & tests folders plus some build.xml files etc

Also, it appears that checking out the DABL SVN also fails:

http://svn.github.com/doctrine/dbal.git

Has anyone else had these problems or able to explain what might be wrong with these repos? (The downloadable version appears to be a different structure again and excludes files that I would like to use to test this library out using the tutorial at http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/introduction.html i.e. the Sandbox files ).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> My checked out version has nothing inside this folder (only the svn folder), yet the online folder structure shows the folders; lib & tests folders plus some build.xml files etc

That's because it's using a Git submodule, I suppose. You'll have to pull the Git submodule yourself, as far as I'm aware, though I don't use git-svn. Probably it will be fixed with:

```
git submodule update
```

Comment: Yeh..thanks, I actually checked it out using Tortoise, I'm unsure how this interfaces with GitHub repos in order to pull these in a seperate modules. Any idea?

Comment: I've just downloaded the TortoiseGIT binary which doesn't seem to have everything it needs? My goodness, is anyone able to make a mirror download of this full repo because I need to get the code.

Comment: ok... I got a bash style ssh client and cloned the git repo with the --recursive instruction, seem to have all the files. What a bunch of hoops.

Comment: I encountered the same problem when trying to pull down the SVN version. I wanted to be able to do an SVN external with it but could never get it working correctly. I just ended up downloading the zip file and including that in my repo.

Comment: @Gary @Jeremy I don't use Tortoise, I'm a shell-guy myself, so I wouldn't know how it handles these situations. Nevertheless, I am happy you finally managed to get it all in one place :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the entire repo I downloaded a git client that uses MingW and used bash to download the repo... to get the GIT sub-modules you must add --recursive so that it downloads the entire tree structure recursively grabbing the sub-module classes.